# Youtube inventory buying by API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have question for Youtube api for vendor

Does youtube provide API to vendor such as DSP, Networks so that they can buy youtube inventory through API or RTB?

Answer (score 0):

Demand Side Platform is not mentioned in [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), only in [Ad Exchange for buyers overview](https://support.google.com/adxbuyer/answer/6138000?hl=en).

[Google will no longer support the small amount of Youtube buying](https://doubleclick-advertisers.googleblog.com/2015/08/focusing-investments-to-improve-youtube-buying.html?utm_campaign=Google-YouTube+Updates&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=21277424&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-_Q9652acg5VUCTJ45pPv3Mtt8xloMM2yZ8glIRUUdA-2epyUGRb2W9Q-y7Gj1rEiCZMdXtxqOQTvIs8vjGy4DpTOlUgg&_hsmi=21277424)

> To continue improving the YouTube advertising experience for as many
>   of our clients as possible, we’ll be focusing our future development
>   efforts on the formats and channels used by most of our partners. To
>   enable that, as of the end of the year, we’ll no longer support the
>   small amount of YouTube buying happening on the DoubleClick Ad
>   Exchange.